# Array - DS HackerRank in C

Tags: arrays, c, reverse

The code is running fine on my Dev C++ IDE, but it keeps failing on the HackerRank IDE.

Am I making some mistake?

Here's a link to the problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/arrays-ds/problem?isFullScreen=true

The function I wrote is as follows, please explain to me where am I going wrong?

```
int* reverseArray(int a_count, int* a, int* result_count) {
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<a_count; i++) {
        result_count[i] = a[i];
    }
    for(j=a_count-1; j>=0; j--) {
        printf("%d ",result_count[j]);
    }
    return result_count;
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to reverse the array, not print it reversed.

Comment: you have not mentioned what is **running** on your IDE and what is **failing** on HR, but the code does not reverse the array, it just prints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is corrct ,you copy the elements of array 1 from end to start in array 2

if you want to reverse your array in the same array,you just use variable temporary to swap the elements like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void* reverseArray(int a_count, int* a) //you return an array (type complexe) so ,you should use void    
{
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0; i<a_count/2; i++)
    {
        temp= a[a_count-i-1];
        a[a_count-i-1]=a[i];
        a[i]=temp;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<a_count; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
     int t[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
     reverseArray(5,t);
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution. And I implemented it too. I passed all the elements of the reversed array a to the array result_count. It shows the output on my ide but won't pass the test case on hackerrank. It is only printing the first two elements after reversing.

Comment: thank you for your help, @MED LDN. I think that the hackerrank IDE is broken for C.

Comment: you should initialize your first value in the for loop of display at 0 and he stopped at the length of array -1 for example ' for(int i=0;i<N;i++ '